# What is the correct engineering name for HDD screw thread?

Tags: hardware, assembly

Everyone who deal with PC and servers assembling knows how does the screw to connect HDD with chassis (tray) looks like.

But how to name it correctly? Is it M3.5 screw or what?

Comment: [Grommet Screws](http://www8.hp.com/emea_middle_east/en/products/oas/product-detail.html?oid=12528005)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_case_screws

Comment: There are different types. 2.5” SSD drives take a shorter screw.  Some drive trays or chassis need a specific head type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

3.5″ HDDs use non-metric, UTS screws: #6-32 UNC. They have #6 diameter (.138″) with 32 tpi (coarse) thread.

2.5″ HDDs and 3.5″ optical drives use metric M3 screws.